# Neo4j Efficiency of Optional Match vs. Where for relationships

Tags: neo4j

I'm still a little new to Neo4j, so maybe I'm missing some obvious writeup somewhere, but I haven't really seen anything for this situation in my searching, so here goes -

I have a situation where I'm making a Neo4j query builder that constructs Neo4j queries from a JSON string and I'm trying to figure out an efficiency question for matching relationships. I need to be able to handle a situation where a relationship exists/does not exist OR a filter is applied (so for example, find all Contacts who have a Company or who have the "active" property set as "false") and I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to handle this.

It seems like nothing I do involving "NOT [pattern]" in the WHERE clause works - so for example, trying

```
MATCH (cn:contact), (cmp:company) 
WHERE NOT (cn)-[]-(cmp)
RETURN cn, cmp
```

throws me all contacts and companies. Because of this, it seems like I absolutely need to do this with an optional match, which is an implementation I can do without much issue.

However, I *can* do something like

```
MATCH (cn:contact), (cmp:company)
WHERE (cn)-[]-(cmp)
RETURN cn, cmp
```

and get only the contacts and companies which are related, meaning that I don't *have* to use an OPTIONAL MATCH for this situation. It would simplify my query parsing to use an OPTIONAL MATCH for both when the relationship exists or when the relationship doesn't, but I've read that multiple OPTIONAL MATCH clauses can result in efficiency issues. Does anyone know if there's an efficiency difference between `WHERE (cn)-[]-(cmp)` and `OPTIONAL MATCH (cn)-[r]-(cmp) WITH cn,cmp,r WHERE r IS NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Updated]

#### Part 1

It looks like your original query (copied below) was intended to get all contacts who do not have a relationship to any company:

```
MATCH (cn:contact), (cmp:company)
WHERE NOT (cn)-[]-(cmp)
RETURN cn, cmp;
```

If so, the above query does not work as you expected because it is actually returning all contact and company pairs that have no relationship between them. That is NOT the same as returning all contacts who do not have a relationship to *any* company. To do the latter, this would work:

```
MATCH (cn:contact)
WHERE NOT (cn)--(:company)
RETURN cn;
```

#### Part 2

In a comment to this answer, you asked if it would be possible to perform a query such as "find all contacts who do not have a relationship to a company whose name starts with the letter 'A'" in a `WHERE` clause (instead of having to use an `OPTIONAL MATCH`). The answer is yes, at least when you use the [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-graphql-neo4j-3-1-preview/) feature added to Cypher in neo4j 3.1 (currently [in beta](https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/)).

First, here is how you might return a collection of such contacts using `OPTIONAL MATCH`:

```
MATCH (cn:contact)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cn)--(cmp:company)
WHERE cmp.name STARTS WITH 'A'
RETURN [x IN COLLECT({cmp:cmp, cn:cn}) WHERE x.cmp IS NULL | x.cn] AS cns;
```

Here is how you can use the new `pattern comprehension` facility of Cypher in 3.1 to do the same thing without an `OPTIONAL MATCH` (the query below returns the result in rows instead of a single collection):

```
MATCH (cn:contact)
WHERE SIZE([(cn)--(cmp:company) WHERE cmp.name STARTS WITH 'A' | 0]) = 0
RETURN cn;
```

Notice how `pattern comprehension` allows you to define a new local identifier, `cmp`, in the specified pattern and also use it locally. This pattern comprehension creates a collection consisting of zeros (could be any value, since we don't actually use it) -- one for each related company whose name starts with 'A'. The `WHERE` clause evaluates to `true` iff the collection is of size 0.

Comment: Ah, that makes some sense. But what if I need to apply arbitrary filters to companies, such as all contacts not related to any company whose name starts with "A"? I believe that the in-line filters such as "WHERE NOT (cn)-[]-(:cmp {name: "name"})" don't work unless they're equal, correct? So I can't do inline filtering for a name that starts with "n", or a name that is not "company", etc.? Would I still have to use the optional match setup for that?

Comment: Oh wow, that looks MUCH more like what I need than the "OPTIONAL MATCH" stuff I was doing - I'm almost out of the office for the day, but I'll be trying this tomorrow and will report back with whether it works for my needs. Thank you so much!